# Tomcat 9 conf file location

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Maven project with this folder structure (from Intellij):

```
...
JavaSources
WebContent
    WEB-INF
target
...
```

config files are located inside WEB-INF and I get exception `java.io.IOException` when they are loaded from

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(this.configFile);
```

the only way to make it works is to move all this files inside JavaSources and when packaged (war) they end up inside target/classes.

Is there a way to keep the file in their original position (inside webcontent/WEB-INF) and to do not get the exception?

When I was running the project on another server (websphere) everithing was fine.

Comment: What kind of project is it - Spring or Java EE ?

Comment: Java EE, java Struts mvc

Comment: Ok !! Maven project doesn't have these structure. Please update or change the project.

Comment: All configuration files need to be there in src/main/resources.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Tomcat to read this files elsewhere?

Comment: You may need to change in pom.xml

Comment: how can I do? I have a fixed folder structure

Comment: Wait I did for one project. But whether it will work or not for this. I don't know